# Datasets in the Google Colab

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I would like to load my own data set with images in order to test my CNN algorithm. I've got two folders, one for training and another one for validation. I have loaded that folders into the Google Drive. I would like to ask how to download folders from Drive into the Colab ? Or maybe there are another better ways to do that ? I look forward to hearing from You soon. Best wishes!

Comment: Full documentation step by step on integration is here: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=c2W5A2px3doP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the folder in drive , go to `google colab` and run the following:

```
#Mounting your Google Drive in the runtime's virtual machine
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

On running the above code you will find a URL from where you can obtain the authorisation code. Paste the code in the space provided and click enter
If you are able to access Google Drive, your google drive files should be all under:

[image: Screenshot]

You can then copy the path and move to the directory using :

```
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/foldername
```